# Sampling distribution of the slope estimator of a stationary non-linear AR(1)

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, estimation, autoregressive, absolute-value

Consider a stationary non-linear AR(1) model
$$x_t = |\theta x_{t-1}|+w_t,$$
where $w_t$ is i.i.d. standard normal.

Given a sample $\{x_0, \cdots, x_n\}$, I want to find an estimate of $\theta$ and using CLT to derive its confidence interval.

Now I think there are two methods to derive the estimator.

1. We can use moments to realize that $E(x_t^2) = \theta^2 E(x_{t-1}^2) + 1$ and thus we have the moments estimator $\hat{\theta}^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{\hat{\mu}}$, where $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i^2$ is the sample mean of the square.
2. Alternatively, one can name $z_i = |x_{i-1}|$ and $y_i = x_i$. We then have the model that $y_t = |\theta| z_t + w_t$. Thus using MLE, we note that $$
   L(x_n, \cdots, x_0 |\theta) = f(x_0)f(x_1|x_0)\cdots f(x_n|x_{n-1}) = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n f_{N(|\theta|z_t, 1)}(y_t).$$
   Ignore the part $f(x_0$), this is exactly the MLE of OLS. Thus the MLE should be $\hat{\theta} = \frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{z}}$.

Yet for both methods I have trouble deriving the distribution of the estimator and failed to give an CI. Any hints will be appreciated.